# Magento 2 - How I can remove default extensions

Tags: magento2, php, module, admin, database

I want to remove some Magento 2 components like: Magento_Analytics, Magento_Braintree ... I just want to have just a product management system. How I can remove this modules completely, files and database tables.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caution: Removing Core Magento modules can stop your ability to update Magento in future.**

Some modules can be removed directly, but others have dependencies in some other modules.

**For example:** **`Magento_Catalog`** module is dependent on **`Magento_Eav`**, **`Magento_Cms`**, **`Magento_Indexer`**, **`Magento_Customer`** etc.

Similarly, **`Magento_CatalogRule`** module is dependent on **`Magento_Rule`**, **`Magento_Catalog`** and **`Magento_Customer`** modules.

So, in my opinion you need to first disable modules one by one and test every functionality after removing particular feature.

Once everything has been tested after disabling particular feature, you can remove module files and related tables (You can get the related tables from the files under Setup folder)

Some features may not be important for you but indirectly those features can be important for running some other module. So be careful.